# Megamenu issue - Clicking menu opens category page for that menu in mobile in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, jquery, luma-theme

I need to resolve issue of responsive megamenu for mobile.

The issue is when I click on the subcategory to opens its child sub-categories the link gets clicked and gets redirected because of which seeing expanded menu gets difficult.

However I tried to locate the code due to which this happens.
Below is the code which is present in **menu.js** file:

```
_toggleMobileMode: function () {
            $(this.element).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
            this._on({
                "click .ui-menu-item:has(a)": function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var target = $(event.target).closest(".ui-menu-item");

                    if (!target.hasClass('level-top') || !target.has(".ui-menu").length) {
                        window.location.href = target.find('> a').attr('href');
                    }
                },
                "click .ui-menu-item:has(.ui-state-active)": function (event) {
                    this.collapseAll(event, true);
                }
            });

            var subMenus = this.element.find('.level-top');
            $.each(subMenus, $.proxy(function (index, item) {
                var category = $(item).find('> a span').not('.ui-menu-icon').text(),
                    categoryUrl = $(item).find('> a').attr('href'),
                    menu = $(item).find('> .ui-menu');

                this.categoryLink = $('<a>')
                    .attr('href', categoryUrl)
                    .text($.mage.__('All ') + category);

                this.categoryParent = $('<li>')
                    .addClass('ui-menu-item all-category')
                    .html(this.categoryLink);

                if (menu.find('.all-category').length === 0) {
                    menu.prepend(this.categoryParent);
                }

            }, this));
        }
```

What I need is that when we click on pseudo element(which shows expansion and contraction) of the sub-category, its child sub-categories should be shown and clicking on sub-category anyways redirects to that particular sub-category
page.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: which Magento2 version you are using?

Comment: Using Magento 2.3.0

Comment: @Nishith, are you using any theme or using default theme only?

Comment: Using default theme menu for mobile

Comment: Default theme's menu works fine in mobile devices as well, may be some menu extension having this issue. are you using any extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your menu.js file as:

```
_toggleMobileMode: function () {
            $(this.element).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
            this._on({
                "click a.ui-corner-all": function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var target = $(event.target).closest(".ui-menu-item");

                    if (!target.hasClass('level-top') || !target.has(".ui-menu").length) {
                        window.location.href = target.find('> a').attr('href');
                    }
                },
                "click .ui-menu-item:has(.ui-state-active)": function (event) {
                    this.collapseAll(event, true);
                }
            });

            var subMenus = this.element.find('.level-top');
            $.each(subMenus, $.proxy(function (index, item) {
                var category = $(item).find('> a span').not('.ui-menu-icon').text(),
                    categoryUrl = $(item).find('> a').attr('href'),
                    menu = $(item).find('> .ui-menu');

                this.categoryLink = $('<a>')
                    .attr('href', categoryUrl)
                    .text($.mage.__('All ') + category);

                this.categoryParent = $('<li>')
                    .addClass('ui-menu-item all-category')
                    .html(this.categoryLink);

                if (menu.find('.all-category').length === 0) {
                    menu.prepend(this.categoryParent);
                }

            }, this));
        }
```

Comment: This was so helpful for IOS device